# Extracting beginning alphabets of a string in bash/ash

Tags: awk, sed, cut, ash

How can I extract the beginning alphabetic letters from a string?
I want to extract alphabets occurring in the beginning before I hit the first non-alphabetic character.

e.g.  If the input string is **abcd045tj56** the output should be **abcd**

Similarly, if the input is **jkl657890** the output should be **jkl**

Can it be done in shell script using awk/sed/cut?

I tried

```bash
echo "XYZ123" | awk 'sub(/[[:alpha:]]*/, "")'
```

But it gives 123 instead of xyz

Then I tried

```bash
echo "XYZ123" | awk '{print (/[[:alpha:]]*/)}'
```

but it gives 1

I want the answer to be XYZ

Comment: Try something like `awk 'match($0,/^[a-zA-Z]+/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file` should work in any version of `awk`.

Comment: why not simply `.... | tr -d -c '[a-zA-Z]'?

Answer (score 5):

Converting my comment to an answer here. Using any `awk` version.

```
awk '
match($0,/^[a-zA-Z]+/){
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}
' Input_file
```

***OR:***

```
awk '
match($0, /[^[:alpha:]]/){
  print substr($0, 1, RSTART-1)
}
' Input_file
```

Comment: Another awk: `awk 'match($0, /[^[:alpha:]]/) {print substr($0, 1, RSTART-1)}'`

Answer (score 4):

You may use this `sed`:

```bash
sed 's/[^[:alpha:]].*$//'
```

This `sed` matches a non-alpha character and everything afterwards and substitutes with an empty string.

Examples:

```bash
sed 's/[^[:alpha:]].*$//' <<< 'abcd045tj56'
abcd

sed 's/[^[:alpha:]].*$//' <<< 'XYZ123'
XYZ

sed 's/[^[:alpha:]].*$//' <<< 'jkl657890'
jkl
```

If you want to do this in `bash` then:

```bash
s='abcd045tj56'
echo "${s/[^[:alpha:]]*}"

abcd
```

Comment: N.B. This will print leading alpha characters even if no substitution occurs i.e. if a string only consists of alpha characters it will print it however the OP stipulated "I want to extract the alphabets occurring in the beginning before I hit first non-alphabetic character". This may be achieved either `sed 's/^[^[:alpha:]].*$//p;d' file` or `sed -n 's/^[^[:alpha:]].*$//p' file`

Comment: I think OP needs to clarify this case when `string only consists of alpha characters only`

Answer (score 2):

Use `grep`:

```bash
$ grep -Eo '^[A-Za-z]+' <<<"XYZ123"
```

to only match alphabetic letters at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk with a non-alphabet as the field separator so you can get the leading alphabets by printing the first field:

```
awk -F'[^[:alpha:]]' '{print $1}'
```

Demo: https://awk.js.org/?snippet=g7eajb

Answer (score 1):

You can use bash's [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to remove the first non-alphabet and all characters after it:

```
s=XYZ123
echo ${s%%[^[:alpha:]]*}
```

Demo: https://onlinegdb.com/OzjGf53T-

Note that this approach has the performance benefit of avoiding the overhead of spawning a separate process.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried
>
> `echo "XYZ123" | awk 'sub(/[[:alpha:]]*/, "")'`
>
> But it gives 123 instead of xyz

You instructed GNU AWK to replace zero-or-more alphabetic characters using empty string, if you wish to do this task using `sub` select non-alpha character followed by zero-or-more any characters, namely

```
echo "XYZ123" | awk '{sub(/[^[:alpha:]].*/, "");print}'
```

gives output

```
XYZ
```

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Answer (score 1):

Using `gnu awk` you can print the first 1 or more alphabetic letters:

```
echo "XYZ123" | awk 'match($0, /[[:alpha:]]+/, a) {print a[0]}'
```

Output

```
XYZ
```

---

If there should be at least a single a non alphabetic character following, you can use a capture group and print that value:

```
echo "XYZ123" | awk 'match($0, /([[:alpha:]]+)[^[:alpha:]]/, a) {print a[1]}'
```

Comment: gnu awk is awesome

Comment: @anubhava If it wasn't for your answers all these years, I would have never got the idea :-)